# robot_self_filter: where does it take the URDF?

Tags: urdf, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
finally I managed to migrate [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_self_filter) into Hydro. For those who are wondering why, it's because I don't want to use MoveIt! for now.

If I launch the node, i receive the following WARNING:

```
[ WARN] [1403614003.986368439]: Some links were included for self mask but they do not exist in the model: lf_upper_leg lf_lower_leg lf_foot rf_upper_leg rf_lower_leg rf_foot lh_upper_leg lh_lower_leg lh_foot rh_upper_leg rh_lower_leg rh_foot
[ WARN] [1403614003.986465197]: No robot links will be checked for self mask
[ WARN] [1403614003.988725771]: No valid URDF frames available, not performing filtering.
```

Of course the links are existing and probably the missing part is the connection with the URDF which is running because I can see the robot on Rviz but maybe the node is not using it for some reason.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174753/robot_self_filter:-where-does-it-take-the-urdf?/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the urdf description is loaded and parsed in robot_self_filter::SelfMask::configure(const std::vector &links). The urdf is accessed though the parameter "robot_description", so throw that sucker in your launch file like so:

```
    <launch>
    <!--   <include file="$(find 3dnav_pr2)/launch/pr2_planning_environment.launch" /> -->

        <!-- Robot Model -->
        <arg name="model"     default="<my_robot>" />

        <!-- Robot Self Filter -->
          <node pkg="robot_self_filter" name="robot_self_filter" type="self_filter" respawn="true" output="screen">   
          ...
          </node>
    
        <!-- Specify URDF file -->
          <param name="robot_description"
                textfile="$(find robot_self_filter)/urdf/$(arg model).urdf"/>
     </launch>
```

Also, for others, you might get this warning:

```
[ WARN] [1439998460.539715578]: Self see links need to be an array
```

when specifying the self_see_links parameter in the launch file. One thing you can try is 1) create a yaml file, 2) add the following array of dictionaries:

```
self_see_links: [{"name":"l_upper_arm_link","padding":0.02,"scale":0.1},
             {"name":"l_upper_arm_roll_link","padding":0.02,"scale":0.1},
             {"name":"l_elbow_flex_link","padding":0.02,"scale":0.1},
             {"name":"l_elbow_flex_link","padding":0.02,"scale":0.1}]
```

and 3) load it in the launch file by replacing "< param name="self_see_links" type="string"... />" with the following:

```
 <!-- Load self_see_links -->
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_self_filter)/launch/<my_self_see_links>.yaml"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [kit_viz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23595/kit_viz/) with karma: 26 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1